# Bash grep ip from line

Tags: regex, bash, grep, ip

I have the file ip.txt which contain the following

```
ata001dcfe16f85.mm.ph.ph.cox.net (24.252.231.220)
220.231.252.24.xxx.com (24.252.231.220)
```

and I made this bash command to extract ips :

```
grep -Eo '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' ip.txt | sort -u > good.txt
```

I want to edit the code so it extracts the ips between the parentheses ONLY . not all the ips on the line because the current code extract the ip `220.231.252.24`

Answer (score 2):

To get the IP within paranthesis all you need is to wrap the entire regex in  an escaped `\( \)`

```
grep -Eo '\((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\)'
```

will give output as

```
(24.252.231.220)
(24.252.231.220)
```

if you want to get rid of the paranthesis as well in the output, look around would be usefull

```
grep -oP '(?<=\()(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?=\))'
```

would produce output as

```
24.252.231.220
24.252.231.220
```

a much more lighter version would be

```
grep -oP '(?<=\()(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{2}?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{2}?)){3}(?=\))'
```

here

`[0-9]{2}` matches the number 2 times

`(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{2}?)){3}` matches `.` followed by 3 digit number three times

The repeating lines can be removed using a pipe to `uniq` as

```
grep -oP '(?<=\()(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{2}?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{2}?)){3}(?=\))' input | uniq
```

giving the output as

```
24.252.231.220
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `awk`

```
awk  -F"[()]" '{print $(NF-1)}' file
24.252.231.220
24.252.231.220
```