# How to print IP address from Shell Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Below is my command line

```
$ps -eaf | grep consul_exporter | grep -v grep
root      4020     1  6 Mar20 ?        4-08:51:18 ./consul_exporter --consul.server=10.1.2.133:8500 --kv.prefix=/ --web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:80
```

I want to get output of IP address(10.1.2.133) alone as output. How to write command line for that?

Comment: How are you executing and retrieving the output in powershell?

Comment: i pasted the command above

Comment: That's not a powershell command...its a shell command... since you have tagged powershell 3 times, please provide code relevant to powershell

Comment: what have you tried so far to extract the ip address? also, what do you want to do with the ip address once you've extracted it ... print to stdout? save in a variable? something else?

Comment: You need to  grep the IP, if you search for 'grep ip' here on StackOverflow, you will find a lot of examples of how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash grep ip from line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566657/bash-grep-ip-from-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a solution which is not elegant, but does the job, just pipe the output of your `grep` command into

```
... | cut -f 2 -d = | cut -f 1 -d :
```

This splits the line first by the `=` and then `:`. If the pattern is not so regular and the IP address can appear anywhere in the line, pipe it into

```
... | grep -oE '([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

The `-o` option just extract the matching pattern(s) from the input.